# Hello everyone! Is there a function to call the wordpress loader?

Tags: plugins

I would like how can I run my wordpress loader on an Ajax load when I send the data I want the loader to appear, is there any function to call the wordpress loader?

Comment: You need to use the plugins by doing it. And the plugin using the [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) Perhaps that would be help you.

Comment: What do you mean with "wordpress loader"? What do you want to do?

Comment: Pre-loader, the screen that appears before the page itself loads